# how to set intent-filter only accept jpg?

Tags: android, mime-types, android-gallery, intentfilter

I want my Activity could accept jpg by Gallery.
so i set

```
Intent picker = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK);
picker.setType ("image/jpeg");
```

But the gallery still shows images of all formats .
how can I let the gallery only shows what I need?
Whether I need to customize the gallery?

Comment: Try getting rid of the spaces in the type string, i.e., use `"image/jpeg"` instead of `"image / jpeg"`.

Comment: sorry, the spaces just the mistakes in the questions.the actual code does not have this error.